# duplicate key error when creating a new mongoose sub-document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

When creating new document and then try to upsert a new sub-document I get this error:

```
Object {error: "E11000 duplicate key error index: sales.users.$gro…p key:
        { : ObjectId('537b7788da19c4601d061d04') }"}
error: "E11000 duplicate key error index: sales.users.$groups.groupId_1
        dup key: { : ObjectId('537b7788da19c4601d061d04') }"
__proto__: Object
```

The sub-document I'm trying to insert is defined as sub-schema that has a groupId field with the requirements {unique: true}, {sparse: true}.  The mongoose method call I'm using to do the upsert is:

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId,
                       { $push: { 'groups': userUpdate} },
                       function (err, obj) where userUpdate = { groupId: groupId }.
```

After dropping the indexes the problem is fixed and this error no longer occurs.

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    active: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        salt: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        hash: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    securityQuestion: {
        question: String,
        salt: String,
        hash: String
    },
    mobile: {
        PIN: Number,
        Number: Number
    },
    createDate: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    updateDate: Date,
    lastLoginDate: Date,
    prevLoginDate: Date,
    passChangeDate: Date,
    locked: Boolean,
    lockDate: Date,
    failedCount: Number,
    failedDate: Date,
    profile: profile,
    preference: preference,
    courses: [UserCourseSchema],
    groups: [UserGroupSchema],
    rewards: [UserRewardSchema],
    roles: UserRoleSchema,
    scores: [UserScoreSchema]
});

var UserGroupSchema = new Schema({
    groupId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        unique: true,
        sparse: true
    },
    joinDate: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    receiveNotifications: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true
    },
    isAdmin: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    isOwner: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    isModerator: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    updateDate: Date
});
```

Comment: Could you extend your question with the schema of the documents and with the indexes used?

Comment: If you're trying to ensure a single user cannot have duplicate groups in `groups`, then this won't work.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/13907257/1259510

Comment: the thing I'm unable to understand is that why does this **userUpdate** have the _id? for precautions, simply delete the _id property from this obj before passing to $push

Answer (score 1):

If you are applying upsert on array of object then this will always create new document as it do not compare sub documents of an array and you have unique index on groupId so it is not allowing you to create new record with the same value. For it you should find that record and if exists, then update it else create new record.

Another best way is to use **$addToSet**.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The {unique: true} requirement on the groupId field means that no two documents in the collection may contain the same groupId, rather than what you intended, enforcing uniqueness of the groupIds within the document.  You can do what you want by using the MongoDB [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#up._S_addToSet) operator instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to update existing group from groups array, $push is not the solution.

```
User.findAndUpdate({_id:userId,'groups.groupId': userUpdate.groupId},
                       { $set: {'groups.$': userUpdate}},
                       function (err, obj){})
```

otherwise as other suggested $addToSet will add the element into set if it exists.

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId,
                       { $addToSet : { 'groups': userUpdate} },
                       function (err, obj){})
```