# Update if object prop doesn't exist in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'd like to `$push` the variable `content` into the database `content` if the `content.hash` isn't already in the database. I don't want to store information again unnecessarily.

```
return shops.updateAsync({
  "user": user
}, {
  "$push": {
    "content": content
  }
})
```

I have a `content` object with the following params.

```
content = {
  "type": "csv",
  "name: "my-csv.csv",
  "content": csvContent,
  "date": new Date(),
  "hash": hash.digest('hex')
}
```

I don't want to ever insert the same CSV into the array. I'd like to ensure that there's only one by checking the hash, if there's a content object in the array with the hash it wouldn't upload or overwrite it.

Here's what I got so far, it's 3 requests :(

```
return users.findOneAsync({
  "user": user,
  "content.hash": content.hash,
}).then(function(exists){
  if(!exists) return false
  return users.updateAsync({
    "user": user
  }, {
    "$pull": { "content": { "hash": content.hash } },
  })
}
}).then(function(){
  return users.updateAsync({
    "user": user,
  }, {
    "$push": {"content": content}
  })
})
```

Comment: Your question is very vague, could you provide more information?

Comment: @PBLC added some more context.

Comment: You wrote that you don't want to overwrite existing object if it's already present in `content` array, but in your code example you're overwriting it with new object. Which is the right behavior?

Comment: I want to overwrite / replace the existing one & I don't want duplicates. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure what your data looks like, but I think it's very close to the answer I gave in another thread. TLDR; unique sub-documents.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29102690/1058776

---

This comes up in google so I thought I'd add an alternative to using an index to achieve unique key constraint like functionality in subdocuments, hope that's OK.

I'm not terribly familiar with Mongoose so it's just a mongo console update:

```
var foo = { _id: 'some value' }; //Your new subdoc here

db.yourCollection.update(
{ '_id': 'your query here', 'myArray._id': { '$ne': foo._id } },
{ '$push': { myArray: { foo } })
```

With documents looking like:

```
{
  _id: '...',
  myArray: [{_id:'your schema here'}, {...}, ...]
}
```

The key being that you ensure update will not return a document to update (i.e. the find part) if your subdocument key already exists.