# Ensuring properties of sub document has unique values in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have the follwoing schema:

```
//Schema A
 const evaluationSchema = new Schema({
"testId": { type: Number, unique: true },
"testCaseName": { type: String },
"marks": { type: Number }
})

//Schema B
const resultSchema = new Schema({
"empId": { type: Number, index: { unique: true } },
"score": { type: Number, default: 0 },
"questionPaper": { type: String },
"evaluationReport": [evaluationSchema], //Embeddeding Schema A
"evaluatedOn": { type: Date, default: new Date() },
"updatedOn": { type: Date, default: new Date() }
})

//Schema C
const batchReportSchema = {
"fa": [{
    "faNo": { type: Number, required: [true, 'Required field'] },
    "result": [resultSchema]  //Embedding Schema B
    }]
};

const schema = mongoose.Schema(batchReportSchema , { collection: 
batchName });
```

You can notice that this is a schema with embedded sub documents. When I insert value, the unique property is not applied on empId & testId properties.

What am I doing wrong? Any pointers or suggestions will help.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914973/mongoose-unique-index-on-subdocument

Comment: I have read the above post. Solution provided by phuhgh, didn't work as expected.